# Load SQL Server Table/View to Azure Data Lake in Parquet / CSV / JSON format using SSIS. Flexible File Destination task keeps throwing error

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I am using OLEDB source to read from SQL Server 2012 and save it to Azure Data lake in Parquet format using Flexible File Destination Task. But I keep getting the following error while the azure flexible file destination task fails in the data flow

[image: Data Flow]

Error Message:

> [Flexible File Destination] Error: Transfer data error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ***Could not load file or assembly*** ***'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'*** or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
> at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.SetStorageExceptionContext(Exception ex, Dictionary`2 exData) at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception ex, String fileSystem, String path) at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.ExceptionHandler.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func, String fileSystem, String path)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.IsFileSystemExist(String filesystem, Boolean swallowForbiddenError, Boolean useListPathApi)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Data.BlobFSClient.CreateFileSystemIfNotExist(String filesystem, Boolean swallowForbiddenError, Boolean useListPathApiToCheckFileSystemExist)
> at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.BlobFSMultipartSink..ctor(AzureBlobFSConnection connection, AzureBlobFSWriteInternalSettings writeSettings)
> at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.AzureBlobFSConnection.CreateSink(IDictionary`2 properties) at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.MultipartWriteSink..ctor(IConnectorPlugin connector, IDictionary`2 connectionProperties, IDictionary`2 writeProperties) at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.ExtensibleFileCommon.DataTransferClientHelper.CreateBinaryDataSink(IDictionary`2 sinkProperties, Guid transferId, Guid activityId, BinaryTelemetryCollector& collector)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.ExtensibleFileComponents.Destination.ExtensibleFileDest.TransferDataToFile()

I have installed integration azure feature pack for SQL Server 2012. Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cross check the folder path and the file name that you have gave in the Flexible file destination editor. Even though, if that results the same error, I suggest you to install the new version of the Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Feature Pack for Azure.

Please check this similar kind of issue where the issue has been resolved after installing the latest version of SSIS.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ssis-azure-flexible-file-task-erroring-due-to-miss/797771?viewtype=all answered by [Bo Fan [MSFT]](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/user/22249/profile).